# Python: How to restructure a vector into multiple 3 dimensional matrices

Tags: python, matrix, vector

So I am a little new to using matrices in Python, and I am looking for the best way to perform the following operation.

Say I have a vector of an arbitrary length, like this:

```
data = np.array(range(255))
```

And I want to fit this data inside a matrix with a shape like so:

```
concept = np.zeros((3, 9, 6))
```

Now, obviously this will not fit, and results in an error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 255 into shape (3,9,6)
```

What would be the best way to go about fitting as much of the **data** vector inside the first matrix with the shape **(3, 9, 6)** while making sure any "overflow" is stored in a second (or third, fourth, etc.) matrix?

Does this make sense?

Basically, I want to be able to take a vector of any size and produce an arbitrary amount of matrices that have the data shaped according to the **3, 9, 6** dimensions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: may be break the first matrix to the components?  take your `data` and split it to `data1` of dimension `162` and rest to the next and shape each one to `3x9x6`, also implement padding by `0` to make sure shape matches?

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def each_matrix(a, dims):
  size = dims.prod()
  padded = np.concatenate([ a, np.zeros(size-1) ])
  for i in range(len(padded) / size):
    yield padded[i*size : (i+1)*size].reshape(dims)

for matrix in each_matrix(np.array(range(255)),
                          dims=np.array([ 3, 9, 6 ])):
  print(str(matrix) + '\n\n-------\n')
```

This will fill the last matrix with zeros.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but this does not seem to work because len(padded) / size evaluates as a float, which can not be used in a for loop.

Comment: You are using Python3.  Use `len(padded) // size` there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough solution to your problem.

```
def split_padded(a,n):
    padding = n - len(data)%n
    numOfsplit = int(len(data)/n)+1
    print padding, numOfsplit
    return np.split(np.concatenate((a,np.zeros(padding))),numOfsplit)


data = np.array(range(255))
splitnum = 3*9*6
splitdata = split_padded(data,splitnum)

for mat in splitdata:
    print mat.reshape(3,9,6)
```

It is very rough and works for `1D` input for array.

First, calculating the number of `0` we need to pad in `padding` and then calculating the number of matrices we can get out of input data in `numOfsplit` and doing the splitting in last line.